# flutter - json - NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart

I am trying to fetch all data from the nutritionx API that matches a text field and display it as a list
The goal is to let the user search food names and have them on the list.

Here is the documentation for nutritionx-
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_q-K-ObMTZvO0qUEAxROrN3bwMujwAN25sLHwJzliK0/edit#

Here is an example response-

```
{
  "branded": [
    {
      "food_name": "Grilled Cheese",
      "image": null,
      "serving_unit": "serving",
      "nix_brand_id": "513fbc1283aa2dc80c000358",
      "brand_name_item_name": "Claim Jumper Grilled Cheese",
      "serving_qty": 1,
      "nf_calories": 560,
      "brand_name": "Claim Jumper",
      "brand_type": 1,
      "nix_item_id": "529e800af9655f6d3500c710"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "Grilled Cheesewich",
      "image": null,
      "serving_unit": "serving",
      "nix_brand_id": "521b95434a56d006cae29678",
      "brand_name_item_name": "Red Robin Grilled Cheesewich",
      "serving_qty": 1,
      "nf_calories": 550,
      "brand_name": "Red Robin",
      "brand_type": 1,
      "nix_item_id": "52cdccf0051cb9eb320054c6"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "Grilled Cheese Melts",
      "image": "https://d1r9wva3zcpswd.cloudfront.net/54ca49ac6f1a024b0f919764.jpeg",
      "serving_unit": "slice",
      "nix_brand_id": "51db37b5176fe9790a8988dd",
      "brand_name_item_name": "Borden Grilled Cheese Melts",
      "serving_qty": 1,
      "nf_calories": 50,
      "brand_name": "Borden",
      "brand_type": 2,
      "nix_item_id": "54ca48fc064e3a791d6737b0"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "Kid's Grilled Cheese",
      "image": null,
      "serving_unit": "serving",
      "nix_brand_id": "521b95494a56d006cae2a612",
      "brand_name_item_name": "Larkburger Kid's Grilled Cheese",
      "serving_qty": 1,
      "nf_calories": 500,
      "brand_name": "Larkburger",
      "brand_type": 1,
      "nix_item_id": "529e80ceea63d4933500fc87"
    }

  ],
  "self": [
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheese",
      "serving_unit": "sandwich",
      "nix_brand_id": null,
      "serving_qty": 1,
      "nf_calories": 348.4,
      "brand_name": null,
      "uuid": "7e79cdfa-bb3f-4f3b-a292-3357aa35d31f",
      "nix_item_id": null
    },
    {
      "food_name": "cheeseburgers",
      "serving_unit": "item",
      "nix_brand_id": null,
      "serving_qty": 1.5,
      "nf_calories": 802.97,
      "brand_name": null,
      "uuid": "5a63f2af-34b2-4137-bf14-5d95eabcf12d",
      "nix_item_id": null
    }
  ],
  "common": [
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheese",
      "image": "https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/1763_thumb.jpg",
      "tag_id": "1763",
      "tag_name": "grilled cheese"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheeses",
      "image": "https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/1763_thumb.jpg",
      "tag_id": "1763",
      "tag_name": "grilled cheese"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheese cheeseburger melt",
      "image": null,
      "tag_id": "5901",
      "tag_name": "grilled cheese burger"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheese cheeseburger",
      "image": null,
      "tag_id": "5901",
      "tag_name": "grilled cheese burger"
    },
    {
      "food_name": "grilled cheese burger",
      "image": null,
      "tag_id": "5901",
      "tag_name": "grilled cheese burger"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code-

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'foodModel.dart';
import 'package:fit_app/fitness_app_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<List<Autogenerated>> fetchDishes(http.Client client, String query) async {
  final response = await client.get(
      'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=$query',
      headers: {
           "x-app-id": "26706c4b",
           "x-app-key": "496693e69b3996ce96fec5eeb79a3c26",
           
      },
      );
  return compute(parseDishes, response.body);
}
List<Autogenerated> parseDishes(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody);
        print(parsed);

  if(parsed is List)
  {
      return parsed.map<Autogenerated>((json) => Autogenerated.fromJson(json)).toList();

  }
  else
  {
    return [parsed];
  }
}

class FoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FoodPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FoodPageState createState() => _FoodPageState();
}

class _FoodPageState extends State<FoodPage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  List<Autogenerated> dishes;
  List<Autogenerated> tempDishes = List<Autogenerated>();

  
  List<Autogenerated> dummySearchList = List<Autogenerated>();
  Widget _widget = Container();
  var energy; 
  @override




  void initState() {
    super.initState();
}
    
  

  Future<List<Autogenerated>> filterSearchResults (String query) async{
    _widget = FutureBuilder<List<Autogenerated>>(
      future: fetchDishes(http.Client(), editingController.text),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          dishes = snapshot.data;
          tempDishes.clear();
          tempDishes.addAll(dishes);
          return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tempDishes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(tempDishes[index].common[index].foodName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), 
                  subtitle: Text('Energy - $energy', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                  ), 
                  color: FitnessAppTheme.nearlyDark,);
          },
        );
        } else 
        {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        }
      
    );
}      
            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return new Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: FitnessAppTheme.darkBackground,
                body: SafeArea(
                  top: true,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            onChanged: (value) async {
                              await filterSearchResults(value);
                            },
                            controller: editingController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: FitnessAppTheme.white),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: FitnessAppTheme.white),
                                labelText: "Search",
                                hintText: "Search",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),
                                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)
                                  ),
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder()
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: _widget,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          
}
```

Here are the models-

```
class Autogenerated {
  List<Branded> branded;
  List<Self> self;
  List<Common> common;

  Autogenerated({this.branded, this.self, this.common});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['branded'] != null) {
      branded = new List<Branded>();
      json['branded'].forEach((v) {
        branded.add(new Branded.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['self'] != null) {
      self = new List<Self>();
      json['self'].forEach((v) {
        self.add(new Self.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['common'] != null) {
      common = new List<Common>();
      json['common'].forEach((v) {
        common.add(new Common.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.branded != null) {
      data['branded'] = this.branded.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.self != null) {
      data['self'] = this.self.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.common != null) {
      data['common'] = this.common.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Branded {
  String foodName;
  String image;
  String servingUnit;
  String nixBrandId;
  String brandNameItemName;
  int servingQty;
  int nfCalories;
  String brandName;
  int brandType;
  String nixItemId;

  Branded(
      {this.foodName,
      this.image,
      this.servingUnit,
      this.nixBrandId,
      this.brandNameItemName,
      this.servingQty,
      this.nfCalories,
      this.brandName,
      this.brandType,
      this.nixItemId});

  Branded.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    foodName = json['food_name'];
    image = json['image'];
    servingUnit = json['serving_unit'];
    nixBrandId = json['nix_brand_id'];
    brandNameItemName = json['brand_name_item_name'];
    servingQty = json['serving_qty'];
    nfCalories = json['nf_calories'];
    brandName = json['brand_name'];
    brandType = json['brand_type'];
    nixItemId = json['nix_item_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['food_name'] = this.foodName;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['serving_unit'] = this.servingUnit;
    data['nix_brand_id'] = this.nixBrandId;
    data['brand_name_item_name'] = this.brandNameItemName;
    data['serving_qty'] = this.servingQty;
    data['nf_calories'] = this.nfCalories;
    data['brand_name'] = this.brandName;
    data['brand_type'] = this.brandType;
    data['nix_item_id'] = this.nixItemId;
    return data;
  }
}

class Self {
  String foodName;
  String servingUnit;
  Null nixBrandId;
  double servingQty;
  double nfCalories;
  Null brandName;
  String uuid;
  Null nixItemId;

  Self(
      {this.foodName,
      this.servingUnit,
      this.nixBrandId,
      this.servingQty,
      this.nfCalories,
      this.brandName,
      this.uuid,
      this.nixItemId});

  Self.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    foodName = json['food_name'];
    servingUnit = json['serving_unit'];
    nixBrandId = json['nix_brand_id'];
    servingQty = json['serving_qty'];
    nfCalories = json['nf_calories'];
    brandName = json['brand_name'];
    uuid = json['uuid'];
    nixItemId = json['nix_item_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['food_name'] = this.foodName;
    data['serving_unit'] = this.servingUnit;
    data['nix_brand_id'] = this.nixBrandId;
    data['serving_qty'] = this.servingQty;
    data['nf_calories'] = this.nfCalories;
    data['brand_name'] = this.brandName;
    data['uuid'] = this.uuid;
    data['nix_item_id'] = this.nixItemId;
    return data;
  }
}

class Common {
  String foodName;
  String image;
  String tagId;
  String tagName;

  Common({this.foodName, this.image, this.tagId, this.tagName});

  Common.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    foodName = json['food_name'];
    image = json['image'];
    tagId = json['tag_id'];
    tagName = json['tag_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['food_name'] = this.foodName;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['tag_id'] = this.tagId;
    data['tag_name'] = this.tagName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Error-

```
Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
E/flutter ( 8271): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:2
E/flutter ( 8271): Tried calling: map<Autogenerated>(Closure: (dynamic) => Autogenerated)
E/flutter ( 8271): Found: map<K2, V2>((K, V) => MapEntry<K2, V2>) => Map<K2, V2>
E/flutter ( 8271): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 8271): #1      parseDishes (package:fit_app/ui_view/add_food.dart:21:17)
E/flutter ( 8271): #2      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:81:34)
E/flutter ( 8271): #3      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:88:65)
E/flutter ( 8271): #4      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:87:5)
E/flutter ( 8271): #5      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:163:22)
E/flutter ( 8271): #6      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:85:35)
E/flutter ( 8271): #7      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:286:17)
E/flutter ( 8271): #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter ( 8271):
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT-

THE ERROR-

```
Unhandled Exception: Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Autogenerated'
E/flutter ( 8671): #0      parseDishes (package:fit_app/ui_view/add_food.dart:30:13)
E/flutter ( 8671): #1      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:81:34)
E/flutter ( 8671): #2      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:88:65)
E/flutter ( 8671): #3      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:87:5)
E/flutter ( 8671): #4      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:163:22)
E/flutter ( 8671): #5      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:85:35)
E/flutter ( 8671): #6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:286:17)
E/flutter ( 8671): #7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
E/flutter ( 8671):
```

EDIT-
i am setting a widget each time and using it in build-

```
    _widget = FutureBuilder<List<Autogenerated>>(
      future: fetchDishes(http.Client(), editingController.text),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          dishes = snapshot.data;
          tempDishes.clear();
          tempDishes.addAll(dishes);
          return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tempDishes[0].common.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print(tempDishes[0].common.length);
            return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(tempDishes[0].common[index].foodName), 
                  subtitle: Text('Energy - $energy', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                  ), 
                  color: FitnessAppTheme.nearlyDark,);
          },
        );

        } else 
        {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        }
      
    );
```

Comment: Can you add `add_food.dart` to the question?

Comment: it's there.. @fartem

Comment: Are you restarted your app or put changes with Hot reload?

Comment: hot reload... @fartem

Comment: Try to restart your app.

Comment: I do get the data just fine, but so is the error @fartem

Comment: And error on line 21 in `add_food.dart` file?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Autogenerated'
E/flutter ( 8671): #0      parseDishes (package:fit_app/ui_view/add_food.dart:30:13)

Comment: Can you post line with error?

Comment: Are you changed something in `add_food.dart` or in `parseDishes` method?

Comment: no @fartem - 
B.T.W - If u would like to take this discussion to discord, tag me with ur username and #

Comment: Right now (from latest error) you have an issue in statement where `parsed` is not a list. You returned `[parsed]` but it is not correct. If it is not a list and you sure that it is a single item, parse it and return a list with one item: `return [Autogenerated.fromJson(parsed)];`.

Comment: so, the error is now gone! but i can't figure out how to present them now in a list, can u help me? @fartem

Comment: Single item in a list? Or you get error that causes at first time?

Comment: There are no errors... I'm just having trouble presenting it in a list-
the page just keep being blank, but if i hot refresh it, the list now shows just fine...

anyway - I edited my original post to show you how did i do it

Comment: Can you also update your code?